# Is it possible to have an element with absolute position to be 'fixed' to the bottom of it's parent container, even when scrolling via CSS/CSS3?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

A variation of this question has been asked many times, but I cannot seem to find any solution for this particular problem.  I have a `<div>` container element with content that has a variable height depending on the elements inside of it.  I want a section of the container to **always** appear at the bottom of the container div, even when the user scrolls the content, they should always see the section at the bottom of the container.  I would prefer not to use `position: fixed` because that is relative to the browser size, not the div, and when I use `position: absolute` I can suffessfully get it on the bottom of my container div, but once I start scrolling, it does not act like a "fixed" element, and scrolls with the content.

Is this possible to achieve this with pure CSS?

Here is my current code:

```css
html, body, .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.content > p {
    margin: 1em;
}

.bottom-section {
    background: skyblue;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">  
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div class="bottom-section">STAYS ON BOTTOM OF CONTENT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this would be to move the "fixed" element outside the scrolling element, and use positioning based on the container to overlay the fixed element atop the scrolling one.  Would that be an option here, or do you need to keep the HTML structure exactly as is?

Comment: @DanielBeck, fortunately I am not fixed to the HTML structure and I can change it.  I will try that and see what happens.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to keep the "fixed" element outside the scrolling element, and use positioning based on the container to overlay the fixed element atop the scrolling one.

The only changes here were to move `.bottom-section` outside of `.content`, and setting `position:relative` on `.container`:

```css
html,
body,
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content>p {
  margin: 1em;
}

.bottom-section {
  background: skyblue;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-section">STAYS ON BOTTOM OF CONTENT</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: this solved the problem!  Can't believe it was that easy.  The only thing to note is that the bottom section will cover part of the scrollbar, but at least in my case I can change the width to be something like 98% instead of 100%.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help, change those two classes as in snippet bellow, comment **overflow: hidden** in **html, body, .container**.

```
  .bottom-section {
  background: skyblue;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  }

  .footer {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: .5em;
  }
```

```css
                  html, body, .container {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                        height: 100%;
/*                        overflow: hidden;*/
                  }

                  .header {
                        background-color: red;
                        flex: 0 0 auto;
                        padding: 1em;
                  }

                  .content {
                        flex: 1 1 auto;
                        overflow-y: auto;
                        position: relative;
                  }

                  .content > p {
                        margin: 1em;
                  }

                  .bottom-section {
                        background: skyblue;
                        bottom: 33px;
                        height: 50px;
                        padding-top: 1em;
                        position: fixed;
                        z-index: 1;
                        width: 100%;
                  }

                  .footer {
                        background-color: red;
                        flex: 0 0 auto;
                        padding: .5em;
                        bottom: 0;
                        position: fixed;
                        width: 100%;
                  }
```

```html
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">  
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div class="bottom-section">STAYS ON BOTTOM OF CONTENT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```